# Raspberry Pi, pinet, install printer

Tags: raspberry-pi

We're having two issues:

1)
We are having a problem installing printer drivers to a Pinet installation on a Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine. The printer is a Xerox Fujitsu DocuCentre-V C3373

There is a GNU/Linux driver available [here](http://onlinesupport.fujixerox.com/setupDriverForm.do?ctry_code=TW&lang_code=en&d_lang=en&pid=DC5C3373).
We've run the shell script in the Ubuntu VM, and followed the instructions, but the printer doesn't show up anywhere.

We also tried following the Ubuntu add printer method, and that does add a generic printer, but the output is quite bizarre.

2)
We were trying to do these things in the Ubuntu VM, because we couldn't figure out how to copy the files to the pinet chroot folder.

Where I have looked around, I've seen instructions for installing CUPS on a raspbian to get AirPlay working. I'm not sure if that is a suitable approach.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: IMHO it's better to ask this question over at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Didn't know about raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, thanks for that.